# Raspberry Pi starting xhost + at startup

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to start    `xhost +`  automatically at startup

I tried to make a startup script and add it to the init.d directory but it didn't work:

```
 sudo nano /etc/init.d/startup.sh
 sudo update-rc.d startup.sh defaults
```

for my Raspberry Pi I'm using Raspbian

Comment: show your startup script

Comment: check section 9.3 http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.3.2

Comment: At what point in the startup does the X server launch? xhost is not very useful without the X server.

Comment: This is a question about Linux startup in general, and not specific to Raspberry-Pi.  You can [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20407156/edit) by mentioning the distro you've installed, what your existing startup process is (GDM?  XDM?  Some other autologin?) and including all the relevant files *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Add "/usr/bin/xhost +" in /usr/share/dispsetup.sh works for me.

$ cat /etc/debian_version

```
10.9
```

$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf | grep display-setup-script

```
display-setup-script=/usr/share/dispsetup.sh
```

$ cat /usr/share/dispsetup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/xhost +
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the output of startup.sh to /var/log/xhost_startup.log using '>'